# how to create shopify script tag in Python

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to create a simple script tag from Python using the shopify API wrapper:

   `shopify.ScriptTag('onload', 'http://test.com').save()`

which does not work because no tag is created, and the code above returns `False`

There is no reference documentation that I could find anywhere for the wrapper, would someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is documentation on [using the shopify_python_api package](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_python_api) which includes a section on [handling errors](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_python_api#Handling_Errors).

Specifically, `save()` is returning false because of a validation error, and the response will have the error message to help you solve your problem, which can be retrieved by calling `.errors.full_messages()` on the script tag object you called `.save()` on.

Comment: thanks. the syntax should be shopify.ScriptTag(dict(event='onload', src='http://test.com')).save()